# Cannot connect to Azure Active Directory Secure Ldap

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, azure-active-directory, apache-directory

I have an app that lets users authenticate with LDAP. In order to test it I wanted to deploy it on a cloud virtual machine and connect it to an Azure Active Directory instance.

I was trying to follow [this](http://www.rebeladmin.com/2016/04/step-step-guide-enable-azure-ad-domain-services/) and [this](http://www.rebeladmin.com/2016/06/step-step-guide-enable-secure-ldap-lightweight-directory-access-protocol-azure-ad-managed-domain/) guide. The steps I have taken:

1. Create a virtual network in Azure.
2. Create an Active Directory in Azure.
3. Activate ENABLE DOMAIN SERVICES FOR THIS DIRECTORY option.
4. Upload a self-signed certificate setup for *.mydomainname.onmicrosoft.com.
5. Activate ENABLE SECURE LDAP ACCESS OVER THE INTERNET.

At this moment I suppose that I should be able to connect to the Ldap server with the IP provided in Azure as EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS FOR LDAPS ACCESS. Unfortunately, I have failed trying to connect to it with Apache Directory Studio.

[image: Apache Directory Studio LDAP connection setup]

What additional steps should I take?

Comment: I have the same prolem. Are you resolved it?

Comment: Yes, I have. However, I don't have access to the Azure portal now. AFAIR there's a setting where you can input allowed ip addresses. You have to type there your (or your company's) ip address.

Comment: Thanks Pawel Koniarski

Comment: after adding your IP address to allow IP will the problem? thanks

Comment: Yeah. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The secure LDAP is on port 636, try that one instead.

Comment: This should go as a comment instead of an answer.